# Spring freemarker multiple template loader paths

Tags: java, spring, freemarker

We are using freemarker templates in our spring boot project for email.

There is one default directory in classpath where all base email templates are stored. And, then there are other directories for client's custom email templates.

What we want is that the template loader should first search for a given email template in the client's custom directory, and if not found, then only look into default directory.

Now, I know we can pass multiple paths in `FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory setTemplateLoaderPaths(String... templateLoaderPaths)`. But does this method maintain the lookup order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory` uses the paths to create a [`MultiTemplateLoader`](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/api/freemarker/cache/MultiTemplateLoader.html), which says:

> A `TemplateLoader` that uses a set of other loaders to load the templates. On every request, loaders are queried **in the order of their appearance** in the array of loaders provided to the constructor.

So yes, the method maintains the lookup order.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Actually, the custom email directory is stored in a cache. And, we had not cleared the cache after updating the client's email directory from default to new one. And, I thought the template path order was not being maintained by loader.
My bad. 
But, thanks again.